# Tkinter Threading causing UI freeze

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I've searched this site (and others) up and down but I can't seem to find the right solution.

I have a client program that connects to a server and automatically sends a message every few seconds, as well as on user command. I'm using multiple threads for this. 
Enter Tkinter: Once I hit the 'Connect' button, my UI freezes, either until the connection attempt times out or until the end of time, should the client connect to the server.

I've tried calling the thread from the button's command parameter, from inside the main loop, and outside the main loop. I've tried putting the main loop in a thread and then creating a new thread for the connection from there.
Nothing seems to be working...the UI continues to hang.

```
class EventSim(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.queue = Queue
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent   

    def initUI(self,IP_Address,Port_Number,Events_Directory):
    #...
    self.Con_Button = Button(frame7,text='Connect', command = lambda:
        self.connect(IP_Text.get(),Port_Text.get(),))

    def connect(self,IP,Port):
        ConnectionThread = Thread(eventsim.con_thread(IP,Port))
        ConnectionThread.start()


def main():
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x310+750+300")
Sim = EventSim(root)
eventsim.readconfig()
Sim.initUI(eventsim.ipa,eventsim.portnum,eventsim.event_dir)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: All tkinter interactions need to be in a single thread. You can't reliably call a tkinter function or method on a tkinter object from any thread other than the one where the root window was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the result of `eventsim.con_thread(IP,Port)` to `Thread(...)` function, so it will wait until the execution of `eventsim.con_thread(...)` completes.  Try changing:

```
def connect(self, IP, Port):
    ConnectionThread = Thread(eventsim.con_thread(IP,Port))
    ConnectionThread.start()
```

to:

```
def connect(self, IP, Port):
    ConnectionThread = Thread(target=lambda ip=IP, port=Port: eventsim.con_thread(ip,port))
    ConnectionThread.start()
```

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you so much. I spent hours yesterday trying to figure that out. I actually tried the lambda approach, but like this:
ConnectionThread = Thread(target=lambda: eventsim.con_thread(IP,Port))
which I guess is still making the same mistake.

Comment: Dude you are a lifesaver! Had the exact same problem!